# Reference request for quantum Teichmuller space

Tags: reference-request, quantum-mechanics, teichmueller-theory

I would like to ask for some detailed reference for quantum Teichmuller theory, better in a mathematical taste. I read a little bit on Kashaev's or Chekhov and Fock's, but find that I need to fill lots of details when I try to proceed. I would like to ask wether there are some good reference in this area, no matter in differential geometrical manner, topological manner, or algebraic manner. Many thanks.

Comment: You might want to try this over on Math Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend:

1. Part D of "Handbook of Teichmueller theory, Volume 1", edited by Athanase Papadopoulos.
2. Lectures on quantum Teichmueller theory, by Rinat Kashaev (School on quantum topology and geometry, Tolouse, 2017):
   http://www.cimi.univ-toulouse.fr/inv3d/sites/default/files/atoms/files/lecture_notes-rinatkashaev-notes_by_nezhlaaghaee.pdf